# How do I delete a directory using mscript

Tags: matlab, simulink

while executing rmdir(<dir_name>,'s') from mscript on an existing directory, an error is returned saying :

```
**Error ID:
[INFO]      [exec]     ---------
[INFO]      [exec]     'MATLAB:RMDIR:NoDirectoriesRemoved'
[INFO]      [exec]     --------------
[INFO]      [exec]     Error Details:
[INFO]      [exec]     --------------
[INFO]      [exec]     Error using rmdir
[INFO]      [exec]     No directories were removed.**
```

PS: i have already checked for directory exists before rmdir.
Also, i tried emptying the directory first(by deleting the contents) then execute rmdir, it still fails.

The delete operation is fine when i run the mscript directly from matlab. Howwever, this fails with the above error message when it is done via maven build

Comment: "_The delete operation is fine when i run the mscript directly from matlab. Howwever, this fails with the above error message when it is done via maven build_" - that hints that the error isn't in the code, but rather caused by the OS environment. If you're using a Windows system, try to launch your build with the "Run as administrator" option. Will it work that way?

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: RCA : I was setting the system default temp. directory to a custom dir. , & was attempting to remove the same at the end of my test case.
Matlab generates a certain .dmr file when the mscript is run for the first time & this file stays in the temp. directory until MATLAB is closed.
Now when i ran the test case from MATLAB, the .dmr is already created/available in the default temp directory.  After this, when the test case sets the custom temp directory everything is fine & deletion is allowed.
However maven build creates .dmr's in custom dir. itself & hence deletion of the dir fails

Comment: Issue still unresolved
Currently i don't have a good idea how to delete the custom temp dir. at the end of the operation(with those .dmr files in it).